# Scripting multi-volume (GNU) `tar` with pre-defined number of volumes

Tags: bash, shell-script, tar, gnu

I've wrote me a little script to test (or extract) a *very* big multi-volume `tar` archive (note: created with GNU `tar`), each of which `00x.tar` chunk will fit onto a standard DVD:

```
#!/bin/bash
d=$(dirname $0)
prf="someprefix"
last=$(ls -1 $d/*.tar | wc -l)

for i in $(eval echo {2..$last}); do echo "n $prf.00$i.tar"; done | tar -Mtvf ./$prf.001.tar --wildcards "$1"
```

Notes:

- The `tar` pipe will work with or without the `$1` parameter given.
- The `d` local will help in the case when both the volume and this script are at another place, but it is run from an arbitrary directory, e. g. your `$HOME`.
- The `last` local will work around the issue of GNU `tar` to never check for number of available volumes in the working directory.
- At this enormous size, `$last` will hardly ever get bigger than 5 (let alone 9) - hence the `00`.

OK, this works. But getting rid of the loop altogether would be *even* better.
Like this (`--wildcards ...` left out here):

```
 eval echo -e "n\ $d/$prf.00{2..$last}.tar\\\n" | tar -Mtvf ./$prf.001.tar
```

However, this only works with exactly *two* volumes. Set `last` to e. g. 4, and another issue will show up caused by `echo` when the pipe is omitted for a test:

```
n someprefix.002.tar
 n someprefix.003.tar
 n someprefix.004.tar
```

Ugh! How did that whitespace get in there? **`tar` does not like that.**

A "fix" (albeit very hackish) is to "`sed` out" the whitespace by inserting a `| sed 's/^ //'` into the above pipe. Quite ugly, but for heck, it works. :)

Can't the whitespace be avoided in the first place, as well?

*(`tr` might not be a good solution here, because we'd need a substitute character  (e. g. `§`) in order to preserve the first space after the `n`; save from dirty hacks, there is no way to tell `tr` "translate all _but_ the first space".)*

Comment: why `eval` and `echo -e` ?

Comment: `eval` is required to resolve the brace expansion: `{2..$last}`. `echo` alone does __not__ accept a variable either as starting or ending value in braces expansion. See also post #170 here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/#comment-59251 Certainly, `eval` can be avoided by just specifying an arbitrary value (like `100`), but I *did* want to match `last` to the *actual* last volume.

Comment: You wrote awfully lot of context for a simple question "why does `eval echo -e "{2..4}\\\n"` output white space at the beginning of rows starting from the 2nd row".

Comment: Right in fact! :-) But by giving all that context, I wanted to avoid foolish answers like "why not omit `eval` and just use `echo -e {2..4}'\n'` instead"? It's because most people always love questioning you *why* you need it in that more "complicated" form and cannot use a "simpler" one (even though they might be able to think of the most obvious answer themselves: "because it's just simplified and (mostly) part of a more comprehensive script").

Comment: @syntaxerror Good to see that you got your answer, but you get downvoted just because your question, with all that specific and long context, is not very useful for someone else who might end up wondering about the same thing, since the context hides the actual question.

Comment: No it does NOT!! I'll clearly contradict you here. Because the *reason* why you may run into this in the first place *IS* very probably `tar`'s strange behavior to always require the user to enter the follow-up volume __manually__, which is a little annoying (to say the least). Hence I was looking for a solution to script it *AND* to use least resources possible. (Remember I *had* a solution, but I was not really satisfied with it.) As the upvoters-to-downvoters is (somewhat) balanced at the moment, I'm certainly not going to cry a river over getting downvoted. ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ eval echo -e "n\ $d/$prf.00{2..$last}.tar\\\n"
n someprefix.002.tar
 n someprefix.003.tar
 n someprefix.004.tar
```

> How did that whitespace get in there?

The answer in a nutshell: this is analogous to the output you'd get if you echoed a line using filename expansion on a bunch of files whose names end with newline.

As described in [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

> Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an optional preamble, followed by either a series of comma-separated strings or a sequence expression between a pair of braces, followed by an optional postscript.

So the shell is evaluating

```
echo -e n\ dir/prefix00{2..4}.tar\\n
        ^preamble^^^^^^      ^postscript
```

And, as with filename expansion, it *inserts a space between each expanded element*, so you get (I'm keeping the \n escape sequence here for clarity):

```
n dir/prefix002.tar\n n dir/prefix003.tar\n n dir/prefix004.tar\n\n
```

QED.

As to your underlying question of how, in a script, to feed `tar` the info to go through multiple volumes, here are two ways:

- Use `seq` to generate the `n` commands:

```
    seq -f "n $d/$prf.%03g.tar" 2 $last | tar -Mtvf $d/$prf.001.tar
```

- Write a short script to generate each new volume name and pass it to `tar`'s `--new-volume-script` option:

```
    echo '#!/bin/sh' > ./newvol
    echo "printf $d/$prf.%03d.tar \$TAR_VOLUME >&\$TAR_FD" >> ./newvol
    chmod +x ./newvol
    tar -Mtvf $d/$prf.001.tar --new-volume-script=./newvol
```

Comment: Nice you could be convinced to write a "neat" answer from your seemingly small comment (which in fact was the solution). If you agree on deleting your solution in the comments, I will do this with my reply as well, so in order to keep a better overview in comments.

Comment: Ok. I was wary of just writing an answer with something rather different from what you were using, and I didn't even know if you had `seq` on your system, so I proposed it first in a comment.

Comment: Oh? Just like the Red Indian tribes used to say, metaphorically: *"White man always likewise cautious like his foot, ere it tread into deep water with crocodile. (Howgh!)"* :-) Well you wanted to be on the safe shore, that's perfectly fine. What would this world be like if man only consisted of daredevils going like the bull at a gate. :)

Comment: Your second option has a bug if your default script is not bash.  You must do this instead to guarantee successful execution `echo '#!/bin/bash' > ./newvol` although I believe the tar info script will inherit whatever shell you use for tar by default. This is because some shells like dash do not support TAR_FD greater than 9

Comment: @jjj Thanks. Answer updated.